# Hosting a database and PHP program on Bitnami LAMP server failing

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, bitnami

I have web game that I have designed for a Uni project that uses a MySQL database and the Smarty template engine.

Locally, the package functions perfectly.  However, I have tried to host it online so that my lecturer can test it, and it's failing.

I have duplicated my htdocs folder on my server, but if I try to access the index page, I get the below error:

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/SWDB/vendor/smarty/templates_c/wrt5ec521ffb8fad9_62962337 <-- thrown in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/SWDB/vendor/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_runtime_writefile.php on line 60

which is included in the below portion of code from the smarty_internal_runtime_writefile.php file:

```
 // write to tmp file, then move to overt file lock race condition
        $_tmp_file = $_dirpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace(array('.', ','), '_', uniqid('wrt', true));
        if (!file_put_contents($_tmp_file, $_contents)) {
            error_reporting($_error_reporting);
            throw new SmartyException("unable to write file {$_tmp_file}");
        }
        /*
```

Comment: you need to either give your website permission to write to that folder or, if that's not possible, change the location it uses for saving these files.

Comment: OK...  Thank you.  I will look into that.  I've never used Bitnami before, so I'll need to investigate this further.  Thanks mate.

Comment: This is general disk permission error, not sure it's anything to do with the Bitnami installer specifically TBH

Comment: Thanks...  I just can't see how I can give the relevant permissions.  I've set a super user account on the database that should have full permission.  That superuser is also in my code (which works locally).  As my kids would say...  it's a bit of a pickle!

Comment: it's not clear if you are running this on a shared hosting account, or a VPS you bought, or some other type of online service? That will affect if/how you can change the permissions.

Comment: I signed up for a free AWS account and provisioned a LAMP server.  This was then linked with Bitnami.  Hope that helps lol

Comment: using what service exactly? A virtual machine, or something else? There are so many ways to host things in the cloud. Anyway you might need to contact AWS support to help you

Comment: It is a virtual Ubuntu server with LAMP preloaded.

Comment: ok well if it's your private VM you should be able to remote onto it (e.g. with SSH) and set the folder permissions from the command line. Find out what user account the apache service runs under (often `www-data` in Linux), and give that account permission to write to the folder in question